# Why the delete query will not execute Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hello i am trying to make a simple delete function but its showing an error

This is the code from the controller:

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    $clientOrder = ClientHasOrder::where('order_id',$id)->firstOrFail();
    $clientOrder->delete();
    return redirect('/')->with('msg','Order Deleted successfully!');
}
```

This is the model code:

```php
class clientHasOrder extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public $timestamps = false;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'order_id',
        'product_id',
        'amount',
    ];
}
```

This is the migration file:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('client_has_orders', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->string('order_id')->constrained();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
        $table->string('amount')->default('200');
    });
}
```

And when i click delete button this is the error im getting:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' 
    
delete from
    `client_has_orders`
where
    `id` is null
```

showing this line in red:   `$clientOrder->delete();`

When i change the name of column from `order_id` to `id` the code works but i dont want to call it `id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it without firstorfail() because you table dose not have an ID.

```php
public function destroy($id)
{
    $clientOrder = ClientHasOrder::where('order_id', $id)->delete();
    return redirect('/')->with('msg', 'Order Deleted successfully!');
}
```

Comment: I will accept in few seconds doesnt allow me now